# display the calendar value

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I display a selected calendar value in a text box? I want the answer in asp.net or C#.

Comment: What calendar are you using ?

Comment: the calender which is availabe in asp.net toolbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the WinForms (I have used `DateTimePicker`) you can handle the `ValueChanged` event...

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Text;
}
```

For an ASP.NET control (I have used the `Calendar` control) you can handle the `SelectionChanged` event...

```
[Markup]
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
    onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>



[CodeBehind]
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
textbox.Text = yourCalendar.SelectedDate
```

More details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate.aspx

Comment: This would give a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'" - you need to convert the SelectedDate value to a string to display it in the textbox.